# How do you make a login page with automatic redirects?

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

For example:

When I type `gmail.com` it redirects me to following link

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin
```

Then when I am done logging in, it redirects me to following link

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
```

My question is how can I do this on my website. I have the following on any page where the user needs to be logged in.

```
 session_start();
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';

 // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
 if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
 }
```

So how can I change this code to let the login page know where to redirect after a successful log in?

I have the following on my login page.

```
ob_start();
 session_start();
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';

 // it will never let you open index(login) page if session is set
 if ( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ) {
  header("Location: home.php");
  exit;
 }
```

How can I change this to redirect to the page?

Comment: The answer to how gmail does it is right in your question: it encodes the next URL to jump to as an HTTP GET parameter.  That's the `&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F` part of the login URL.

Comment: @PMV So if I add that to the end of my header location, is that where it will go after I login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step make GET url the current page

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

if you used link make sure the link is

```
echo '<a href="login.php?q='.$actual_link.'">Login</a>';
```

Make file login.php for check login

```
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$gotopage = $GET_["q"];

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) //Check if error or not isset login and redirects to index.php
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) //Check if success login and redirects to home.php
{
    header("Location:".$gotopage);
}
```

Comment: So my question is if there is a universal solution working across many pages?

Comment: The header argument on line 55 does not take any variables, it disregards variables, i do not know why

Comment: so, your question is, is any way to redirecting in javascript, is it right?, try this`<script>window.location.replace("http://yoururl.com/login.php");</script>`

Comment: what you have in your answer is what I want but I do not know why the variable in the header location is disregarded, and it redirects to only what is in quotation mark

Comment: Try change this `<?php }else{ header("Location: home.php"); } ?>` to `}else{?><script>window.location.replace("http://yoururl.com/home.php")</script><?php } ?>` I use redirect with javascript.

Comment: What would i do for line 55?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156960/discussion-between-abed-putra-and-riz-waan).

Answer (score 0):

I have found using cookies is easier. I created a cookie with user address before sent to login page, then redirected them back after the completion of login page.